# To create a page then get data and store it in java script object then send data to .Net with HTTPPOST

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

My senior asked me to create a page get data and store it in java script object then send data to .Net with HTTPPOST.Then Call webservice in .Net .But I absolutely have no idea how to do that and where to start... Can someone light me up with some simple examples

I don't know how to get data from this input and store it in javascript object and send data to .Net with HTTPPost then use web service in .NET.I need simple examples to do so I appreciate your help.

I've been googling how to do it but it's been a while i can't find an answer

Comment: Try to do it yourself, if you face any problem during doing that, ask a question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your data comes from the user input:

### Step 1: Create an input.

```html
<input type="text" id="myFirstInput" />
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Add those code to your HTML and it will ask the user to input something.

### Step 2: Get the data in your input.

```
var submit = function () {
    var myValue = $('#myFirstInput').val();
}
```

Add those code to your `script` tag in your HTML under `jQuery` loads scripts.

It will get the data user input.

### Step 3: Send the data to your server.

Modify your javascript. Sent the data you get to your server.

```
var submit = function () {
    var myValue = $('#myFirstInput').val();

    // Send your data!
    $.post('/api/example', { data : myValue }, function (response) {
        alert('success!');
    });
}
```

### Step 4: Get the data on your server

Create a new controller called `APIController`.

```cs
public class APIController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Example([FromBody]dynamic jsRequest)
    {
         // Use: jsRequest.data.
         return Json(new { });
    }
}
```

And your task is completed.

BTW, I strongly suggest you learn the basics and try to break your question to smaller ones and google them before asking questions.

Answer (score 0):

Break up your '*problem*' in smaller questions:

1. [store data in javascript object site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=store+data+in+javascript+object+site%3Astackoverflow.com)
2. [send data to .NET with HTTPPOST](https://www.google.com/search?q=send+data+to+.NET+with+HTTPPOST+site%3Astackoverflow.com)
3. ....

Remember, you are not the only one asking these kind of questions, so probably someone has already answered ...

P.S. Reading this might help too: [How to search on google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/134479?hl=en)